# site.css styles not being applied to Docker image with Visual Studio 2017 Docker build

Tags: visual-studio, docker

- I am using Windows to build a Linux container with Visual Studio 2017
- I make a change to site.css in my ASP.Net Core web app, and a minor textual change to the home page to show the app current version.
- I build and debug my docker image locally: SUCCESS (I see the changes)
- I push my image to docker hub: SUCCESS!
- I update my kubernetes deployment to pull the new image from docker hub: SUCCESS (I see the new image pulled, and I see the version change on the home page)
- FAIL: I don't see the css changes!

If I open up the Chrome dev toolbar, it does not appear to be getting the right site.css - I can tell this by inspecting the elements - they have some other css being applied, not mine!
If I view source, it is referencing the minified version of the css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.min.css?v=kHvJwvVAK1eJLN4w8xygUR3nbvlLmRwi5yr-OuAO90E" />
```

**Here is the OOB Dockerfile from Visual Studio:**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY SupportTicket.sln ./
COPY ST.Web/ST.Web.csproj ST.Web/
COPY ST.AppServicesLib/ST.AppServicesLib.csproj ST.AppServicesLib/
COPY ST.SharedInterfacesLib/ST.SharedInterfacesLib.csproj ST.SharedInterfacesLib/
COPY ST.SharedEntitiesLib/ST.SharedEntitiesLib.csproj ST.SharedEntitiesLib/
COPY ST.SQlServerRepoLib/ST.SQLServerRepoLib.csproj ST.SQlServerRepoLib/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/ST.Web
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ST.Web.dll"]
```

## Question

If I can view the website correctly with a debug build, why is it not appearing correctly in the pushed image? (I expect the images to be identical)
How do I fix this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary answer (this is a workaround, and I would still like to get an answer on the central question as to why the debug website container != the deployed container):

Comment out the minifier configuration in **bundleconfig.json**.  This got it working for me.  (But now I don't have any minification!):

```
// Configure bundling and minification for the project.
// More info at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808241
[
  //{
  //  "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
  //  // An array of relative input file paths. Globbing patterns supported
  //  "inputFiles": [
  //    "wwwroot/css/site.css"
  //  ]
  //},
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optionally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Also, I commented out, and updated, the stylesheet reference in **_layout.cshtml**:

```
<environment exclude="Development">
       <!-- etc -->
        @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />*@
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
```

Any better answers, greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following link was useful: https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/217